# Conditional Check of Props Not Working In Styled-System

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to create a Button component using Styled-Components and Styled-System.  In general, it works fine.  However, when it comes to doing a basic prop test, I can't seem to get it to work.

For instance, the following code is not working for me:

`background-color: ${props => (props.bg ? 'red' : 'blue')}`

Whether or not I have set the `bg` prop, the background-color is always red.  In other words, the following components both return a red background:

```
<Button>Button</Button>
<Button bg="primary.base">Primary</Button>
```

Any idea how I can conditionally check if a prop is set?

In case it helps, I am referring to the `Button.js` and `layout.js` files in the `Components` folder here: https://codesandbox.io/s/gatsbystarterdefault-rbzo8?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1:** Are we sure that the red background is due to the hover of line 33 of the Button.js file? Change it to orange in order to be sure.

**Option 2:** Maybe yout custom styles are overwritten by the ones you passed from line 35 to 44:

```
  ${borders}
  ${boxShadow}
  ${buttonSize}
  ${fontSize}
  ${height}
  ${lineHeight}
  ${minWidth}
  ${space}
  ${color}
  ${buttonStyle}
```

Hoist that part before you custom Button styles and try it again.

**Option 3:**   Set the default blue color and overwrite it if property bg exists. In order to do it, replace line 33 of the Button.js with this:

```
background-color: blue;
${props => props.bg && css`background-color: orange;`}
```

**Note:**   The parenthesis in the aforementioned line 33 is not necessary:

background-color: ${props => props.bg ? 'red' : 'blue'}